# cURL GET request working on localhost, but no on web server

Tags: php

I am fetching an array from a website using cURL.
It works perfectly on localhost but when I uploaded it to Server it returns NULL.
This is my code:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
$url = "http://staging.quran.com:3000/api/v3/chapters?language=en";
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_PORT => "3000",
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

Note: It only doesn't work with this URL
It is working with all the other URLs e.g Google.com etc

It means my server's cURL request is enabled!

Anyone can please help me!!

Comment: You have to check if some options like allow URL fopen etc are set to true.

Comment: As I have mentioned it is fetching from other URLs, it means they are enable...

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Try debugging using the answer provided in the dupe. If you still can't find the solution, post the attempt here.

Comment: My best bet is that the server from which cURL is running doesn't have the access to that domain. Is it recently registered one?

Comment: cURL isn't returning any error

Comment: Uh... That's crazy... I really believe unable to access that specific URL should be the error. I'll reopen the question. Let's see if others are able to answer. `:)`

Comment: We don't have to register our domain, Its FREE

Comment: Wait what? What's free? Which domain are you using? Just tell the TLD.

Comment: www.dostana.biz

Comment: Weird. It works for me. `:/`

Comment: Then what can be the problem?

Comment: Not sure boss. Looks like everything seems to be right if you are able to access other websites... So... Let's wait for others' opinion on this.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `$url = "http://staging.quran.com:3000/api/v3/chapters?language=en"`. Did you paste your entire code?

Comment: I miss in pasting

Comment: @NadirAbbas Anything worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `var_dump($response)` instead of `echo $response;` , if I'm not mistaken `$response` is a json object not a string.

Comment: Yes, Also checked, But returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

go to the following stackoverflow link
[Curl request not working on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075213/curl-request-not-working-on-live-server)

check the server that you are requesting is blocking requests from your server. try to ping to that server( http://staging.quran.com:3000/api/v3/chapters?language=en ) from the shell of your server

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with your code, furthermore it's working on localhost and on the server when accessing to other websites.

Make sure the server **allows** outgoing connections on **port 3000**

I'm pretty sure the problem lies there.