# Constant error with curl for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, twitter

I just installed the curl library for codeigniter written by [Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk). 
I keep getting this error

> "Error: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
>   Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

I've checked across the internet and the general solution was to set the following values to FALSE and 0 respectively

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE;
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0;
```

Comment: i forgot to point out that i have tried this and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: check this doc: http://ademar.name/blog/2006/04/curl-ssl-certificate-problem-v.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer

Comment: and show your `curl_init()` please.

Comment: i was able to solve the problem thanks to the links provided by bora ,.. i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curlReturned = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$curlReturned)
{
trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the CA that curl dosn't have, and load it with:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, “pathto/cacert.pem”);
```

or if you don't want the safty of SSL, just turn of it,
Boras link describes this more deeply