# cURL requires CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=FALSE

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I was using cURL on my localhost for the longest time and all the sudden I noticed it no longer works unless I explictly set the option, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`=`FALSE`.

I have no idea how/when this changed but I'm using NGINX and PHP and I can verify that this is not a specific issue to a specific requested host. I'm getting blank responses from `https://site1.com` and `https://different-site.com`.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I love this [hidden gem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12293898/), it explains how you can use certificates to verify hosts.

Comment: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: @DaveChen and -@Young thanks but do you have a sense as to why I didn't need to supply a certificate before, but do now?

Comment: From [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6400746/) on the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6400300/). cURL used to bundle CA certs, but now you must download them manually and pass them to cURL or give a [default value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php#ini.curl.cainfo) within PHP.

Comment: those answers are 2 years old, this problem has arose for me in the last month.

Comment: I would ask if any changes were made to the environment, i.e, *.ini files being reset or having files moved (CA certs missing). Other than that, I don't think cURL would work while having `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1` and no certificates to verify the peer with. Could you provide a little more information on your host? Is it shared, homeroot, vps, dedicated?

Comment: I'm the sole user of the host, its just my mac laptop, so I likely screwed something up. I must have installed a certificate at some point but would have no idea when I did and more troubling why it was removed. I'm still a newer developer so trying to slowly ween away from copy/paste things I learn about on the internet.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Thanks to Dave Chen's suggestions, I realized I must have misplaced my certificate. The problem is solved by this certificate which is provided by the cURL creator (extracted from Mozilla): https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

So after downloading this cacert.pem file into your project, in PHP you can now do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

Alternatively, this can be set globally by adding the following to your php.ini

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

Comment: I'm not a security expert but downloading .pem file form insecure source (http:) can be trusted?

Comment: where can i place this curl_setopt syntax if im using codeigniter

Comment: About file name, some programs will expect this file to be named ```ca-bundle.crt``` (in the correct path)
More details [here](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html)

Answer (score 5):

**If you are using WampServer, notice this:**

You must put the *absolute path* in CURLOPT_CAINFO, for example:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\wamp\www\your-project\cacert.pem')
```

Don't use relative path: curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem') **because it doesn’t work**.

Answer (score 1):

The value for CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER by default is TRUE as of cURL 7.10.

Hence you may need to explicitly set it to FALSE to prevent CURL from verifying the certificate.