# How can I access the Puppet API using PHP

Tags: php, curl, puppet

I am trying to get a PHP script to access the Puppet API. I have spent 2 days searching and cannot believe that I cant find any info whatsoever (only puppet modules for installing PHP).

I am just trying to use PHP and curl but I am not able to get any kind of response, error or anything. Here is my (very basic) attempt to get the cert from the puppet master:

```
function get_data($url) {

    $request_headers = array();
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept: s';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}    
    $response = get_data('https://<puppet master>:8140/production/certificate/ca');
```

All I am trying to replicate is a curl call that works from my server:

```
curl -k -H "Accept: s" https://<puppet master>:8140/production/certificate/ca
```

I have a feeling that there is probably something obvious I am missing but, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: So... why don't you set that `Accept: s`  header in your PHP script?

Comment: Doh, I missed adding that to my question, thanks for pointing that out (edited). I still get no response data.

Comment: OK, next one from the commandline not included: set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false. If that still doesn't work, try `curl_error($ch);` to make it show you why it fails.

Comment: Wrikken, that did the trick! Thank you very much. I think my frustration kept me from seeing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Wrikken and Glen for getting me on track. Once I set the curl_setopt options correctly, it works as expected.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

Comment: Just a heads up, not verifying the SSL cert used in the connection could make you vulnerable to certain man-in-the-middle type attacks on your API requests. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972719/3147637) on SO for a possible solution without using the above method.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Glen. I will continue to work on getting it coded properly now that I at least have something to work with. You guys are very helpful!   

UPDATE: Glen, that post was very helpful and I now have it working properly. Once again, thank you (and Wrikken)!