# Wowza Cloud API: curl requests

Tags: php, curl, wowza, php-curl, wowza-transcoder

I can't make it work.. :( I have this function (for create passthrough transcoder), when I run I see `NULL` in the web. If I test directly from the browser with the url, it does notify me that there is a problem an auth (`apikey` and `acceskey`)

```
function createPassthrough($name, $source_url, $recording = null)
{
    $url = "https://sandbox.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1/transcoders";

    $json = '{
                "transcoder":{
                    "billing_mode":"pay_as_you_go",
                    "broadcast_location":"eu_belgium",
                    "delivery_method":"pull",
                    "name":"prueba",
                    "protocol":"rtsp",
                    "source_url":"url_camara",
                    "transcoder_Type":"passthrough",
                    "low_latency":true,
                    "buffer_size":0,
                    "play_maximum_connections":100,
                    "stream_smoother":false
                    }
            }';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'wsc-api-key:' . $apiKey,
        'wsc-access-key:' . $accessKey,
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($obj);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for curl errors after `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.

```
// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks u! 

I have tried and it shows the error that I don't understand:

cURL error (60): Peer certificate can not be authenticated with given CA certificates

What can be?

Comment: You need to add these curl options curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: please do var_dump of your $apiKey and $accessKey. You should declare them as input params of your function or give a value to them inside the function .

Comment: Yes! I had already find at the error, and as you say. Now it works. Thank you very much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971983/curl-requires-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-false

Comment: Yes, I noticed and modified it:

'wsc-api-key:'. $this-> apiKey,
'wsc-access-key:'. $this-> accessKey,

Thx!