# PHP JSON response is not loading from URL

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

Here's the link that provides JSON response: https://www.instagram.com/p/CDq1KJPJcTN/?__a=1

Simple copy and paste the URL in browser gives JSON response. But When I try to access the same in PHP using file_get_contents or cURL, it's showing Instagram's html page code

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
ini_set("allow_url_include", 1);

$context = [
            'http' => [
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36',
                ],
            ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/p/CDq1KJPJcTN/?__a=1', false, $context);
```

cURL:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.instagram.com/p/CDq1KJPJcTN/?__a=1');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo $query;
```

When I use rest api test tool (https://resttesttest.com/). It's giving JSON response only. I think some important header is missing, which I'm unable to figure out.
Content-Type:application/json & Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * are given.

Comment: dunno file_get_contents, but for cURL, you need to setup connexion for secure (`https`) target host.

Comment: When I run that code I get a JSON String, a Big one but definitely a JSONString

Comment: @YvesLeBorg My php file is using https only

Comment: Probable cause: If you believe you need to set `allow_url_fopen` then I guess it is not set. However you cannot change its value from anywhere but the `php.ini` file. Wouldn't be much of a secure setting if you could

Comment: @RiggsFolly did you run that in PHP? Opening the link directly in the browser gives JSON String. But I need same JSON to be read in my PHP

Comment: I ran it using the PHP CLI, works fine, with or without the use of the context

Comment: I ran the `file_get_content()` and `echo $date;` to see JSON

Comment: The curl output nothing

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried changing the settings in php.ini, restarted the server. Still it's giving me the html code not JSON String. Is it anything to do with header?

Comment: Is that ALL the code in that script? I assume you have a `<?php`

Comment: `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
ini_set("allow_url_include", "on");

require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I used your exact code, it worked for me under the CLI, I also ran it woithout the context and that also ran

Comment: Try without the 3 headers, they are not needed

Comment: Tried, it's not working. Is there any other way to read that?

Comment: Tried you cURL code as is, worked for me.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, I ran the same code, it's showing website instead of JSON

Comment: @DeebashVFX different curl, different php, different OS ... who knows. Also, how do you 'see' what it shows ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I'm using AWS LAMP server PHP 7.2,  cURL 7.16.1

Comment: @DeebashVFX using 7.2, curl 7.56.1 , osx

Comment: @DeebashVFX : are you certain that the AWS instance has an internet Egress route ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried the same php file in localhost, it's working. Giving exact JSON String. Can't figure out whats issue in server

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I don't know about internet Egress route. But i'll check it and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.instagram.com/p/CDq1KJPJcTN/?__a=1');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $query;
```

Using file_get_contents worked for me in local

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", TRUE);
ini_set("allow_url_include", TRUE);

$context = [
            'http' => [
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36',
                ],
            ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/p/CDq1KJPJcTN/?__a=1', false, $context);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this code but, It's giving empty page.

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: Make sure that you enabled the extension extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini

Comment: Thanks! This answer is working in localhost. But not in server, I'm looking for other problems.

Comment: May be ssl certificate issue. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971983/curl-requires-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-false

Comment: In server try curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

Comment: I dont think SSL is issue here. Because file_get_contents also not working in server but working in localhost.

Comment: ini_set("allow_url_fopen", TRUE); // use TRUE instead of 1