# PHP APİ CURL Get Null

Tags: php, null, php-curl

```
$curl      = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl   , [

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>TRUE,

CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ortam.etu.edu.tr/Services/get_user_card_information/?apikey=XXXXXXXXX&username=ZZZZZZZZZZ',

 ]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($response, TRUE);

var_dump($response);
```

I was able to get a response from a different API call, but I cannot get a response from this API, it comes back as NULL.

https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2023-12-01&end_date=2023-12-08&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This API works correctly.
​

Comment: Your curl request is very, very basic - my guess would be that the lack of the `useragent` in the options might be why but as it is an SSL protected endpoint it might be that you should add the parameters to negotiate https connections

Comment: Looks as though there is something wrong with the certificate for that site, try using http instead of https.

Comment: You **SHOULD NOT** share any private credentials like api keys in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for any errors in the cURL request using `curl_error` function which returns any error happens in the request phase:

```
$error = curl_error($curl);
var_dump($error); // Output: string(63) "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
```

That's means that there is an issue with the SSL certificate on the requested endpoint.

To solve this, you need to disable the SSL verification using

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
```

or to request the **UN-SECURED** http like:

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://ortam.etu.edu.tr/Services/get_user_card_information/?apikey=ZZZZZ&username=XXXX',
```

Note the `http://ortam.` instead of `https://ortam.`

However, **this is not a good idea at all to disable the SSL verification.**

Answer (score 1):

If you making a request to API endpoint which has SSL Certificate you should set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` options to `false`

> Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15237205/12571947

> According to documentation: to verify host or peer certificate you
> need to specify alternate certificates with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option
> or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH
> option.

### Not Recommend (Only for Development)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, // Skip SSL Verification
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // add this line
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://ortam.etu.edu.tr/Services/get_user_card_information/?apikey=XXXXXXXXX&username=ZZZZZZZZZZ"
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

## Recommend

> Answer Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972719/12571947

The problem is solved by this certificate which is provided by the cURL creator (extracted from Mozilla): https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

So after downloading this cacert.pem file into your project, in PHP you can now do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

Alternatively, this can be set globally by adding the following to your php.ini

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

Comment: Generally this is a bad idea, you should make sure that you have valid certificates and the appropriate files set up on your machine running php.

Comment: @SimgeKoçak Sorry you should not use my previous answer and check the new answer. I posted just now. You should use the Recommend way for production.