# HWIOAuthBundle - SSL certificate

Tags: symfony, curl, ssl, hwioauthbundle

I am developing a website with Symfony2 on a localhost[Wamp] running on Windows, I need for login to the sitewith HWIOAuthBundle[facebook, Google] but everytime when I click on login I get this error message:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

How I can avoid this message for the moment?

Answer (score 5):

Download the file http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
and add this to your `php.ini`

```
curl.cainfo="path/to/your/cacert.pem"
```

and restart your server !

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053))

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to do this on Windows 10 to create a Symfony 3 project. I'm working with XAMPP.

Answer (score 3):

download curl ca cert:

http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="cacert.pem"
```

Comment: where to add this cmd and what do you mean with home directory? I'm using windows [wamp]