# "SSL certificate próblem" when conneting to eBay

Tags: xml, ssl, curl, categories

I want to retrieve categories from ebay. This is my code:

```
function getCategories(){


    $endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";
    //$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

    $api_dev_name = "XXX";
    $api_app_name = "XXX";
    $api_cert_name = "XXX";
    $auth_token = "XXX";

    $headers = array(
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 819',
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: '.$api_dev_name,
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: '.$api_app_name,
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '.$api_cert_name,
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetCategories',
        'X-EBAY-API-OPERATION-NAME: GetCategories',
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: EBAY-US',
        'Content-Type:text/xml'
    );

    $xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
    $xmlRequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<eBayAuthToken>{$auth_token}</eBayAuthToken>";
    $xmlRequest .= "</RequesterCredentials>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>";
    $xmlRequest .= "</GetCategoriesRequest>";
    $xmlRequestEncode = utf8_encode($xmlRequest);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl,
        array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmlRequestEncode,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!$response) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }

    curl_close($curl);
}

getCategories();
```

`$api_dev_name`, `$api_app_name`, `$api_cert_name`, and `$auth_token` are valid, active, and set in production environment.

I get this error from curl:

> Error: "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" - Code: 60

Why do I get this error?

Comment: The client code (curl) is unable to validate the SSL certificate being presented by the remote site.  The curl package must have a way of specifying a certificate store for validating certificates.  Probably a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6400300/18157

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP CURL HTTPS causing exception SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer)

Comment: Great! It helps. Since I don't want to use own certificate I just add CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false to curl options. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

According to OpenSSL's `s_client`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect svcs.ebay.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=eBay, Inc./OU=eBay Site Operations/CN=svcs.ebay.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
---
...
```

So you need to trust the `Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2`. You can download form [Verisign Root Certificates](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots). Grab the one labelled ***Root 1*** with fingerprint `85 37 1c a6 e5 50 14 3d ce 28 03 47 1b de 3a 09 e8 f8 77 0f`.

Once you download the ZIP file, you can find it in the folder *Generation 2 (G2) PCAs*. Its named *Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2.pem*.

Finally, tell cURL to use the root certificate you downloaded. I can't get to the cURL docs at curl.haxx.se at the moment, so I can't tell you what to call to do it.

***DO NOT*** load the CA file with the hundreds of CAs. You know Verisign certifies eBay's certificates, so only use the required Verisign CA. Don't allow an attacker to get you to believe otherwise (for example, Truswave claiming they certify eBay).

Answer (score 0):

just add new two lines in curl_setopt_array,

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // new code
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false // new code
```