# SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I have a php site and get this error when the code try to use curl to make api calls to my https site.

> ExtCurlJsonClient-Error was: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I tried to do wget on my https site and get the ERROR: cannot verify xxxxxx.com's certificate, issued by `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA':

So its a problem with certificate but certificate seems to be installed properly as i can see the green lock on browser address bar.

> NOTE: Also this problem started appearing when i updated the SSL
>   certificate on my site. It was not happening with older ssl
>   certificates.

Why is this happening!

Comment: Do you send the CA certificate with your site certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL HTTPS causing exception SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer)

Comment: How do you send the certificate? Was this a change from php 5.4 to 5.6? This is not curl.