# CurlException: [curl] 51: SSL: certificate verification failed

Tags: php, symfony, curl, ssl

Can't figure out what could be:

In my local environment, after I updated my OSX to the last version of Yosemite, I get this error:

```
CurlException: [curl] 51: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5) [url]
```

I'm using Symfony2 so it is related to PHP. I tried to reinstall openssl but nothing happen.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm find that all PHP-based SSLs fail (and have done since Beta 2). Can't find a solution yet; interested to know if you can find a solution.

Comment: I think its an error with cURL and Yosemite. Try in a command line `curl --cacert /path/to/cert.pem https://url`. I get the same '51' error. Telling the PHP not to set a cert seems to then work for me. Take a look at https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone already asked a similar question, please look here: [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)

also, there is an article here: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: I already tried these solutions but are not working. However for this moment I found a little trick (see the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the certificate chain for whatever domain is giving you this error. For me it was googleapis.com

```
openssl s_client -host www.googleapis.com -port 443
```

You'll get back something like this:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleapis.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
```

*Note: I captured this after I fixed the issue. Also, your chain output will look different.*

Then you need to look at the certificates allowed in *php running under apache*. Run phpinfo() in a page.

```
<?php echo phpinfo();
```

Then look for the certificate file that's loaded from the page output by searching the page for `openssl.cafile`:

```
openssl.cafile openssl.cafile /usr/local/php5/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

This is the file you'll need to fix by adding the correct certificate(s) to it.

```
sudo nano /usr/local/php5/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

You basically need to append the correct certificate "signatures" to the end of this file.

You can find some of them here:

- https://pki.google.com/
- https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/index.html

They look like this:

[image: example certificate image]

(*Note: This is an image so people will not simply copy/paste certificates from stackoverflow*)

If you need to convert a .crt to pem, you'll need to do something like this:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in GIAG2.crt -out GIA2.pem
```

Once the right certificates are in this file, restart apache and test.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for this problem is to unset the value for **SSL_CERT_FILE**

Run the command :

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=""
```

And then try performing the desired actions and it will work properly.

Reference : [Curl 'certificate verification failed' on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737490/curl-certificate-verification-failed-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade curl from 7.37.1 (shipped with beta2) to 7.37.0

Answer (score -1):

Add those options to ignore ceritificate:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);