# Curl 'certificate verification failed' on mac

Tags: curl, homebrew

On the Mac, `brew install something` (chromedriver in this case), yields:

```
curl: (51) SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)
Error: Failed to download resource "chromedriver"
Download failed: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.22/chromedriver_mac32.zip
```

Que pasa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Env var SSL_CERT_FILE was set to something by some other tool previously. This ...

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=""
brew install something
```

... fixes the problem

Comment: Or `unset SSL_CERT_FILE`.