# How can we retieve values from an API

Tags: php, api, curl

I have a trouble .From  HunterExpress API, I want to fetch freight charge amount for that passing  postCode,product dimensions/weight etc I am using the following  code to fetch freight charge

```
$data = array(
    'username' => "xxx",
    'password' => "xxx",
    'customerCode' => "DUMMY",
    'fromLocation' => array( "suburbName"=> "MELBOURNE", "postCode"=> "3000", "state"=> "VIC"),
    'toLocation' =>array( "suburbName"=> "SYDNEY", "postCode"=> "2000", "state"=> "NSW"),
    'goods' =>array( "pieces"=> "2",
    'weight' => "3",
    'width' => "10",
    'height' => "20",
    'depth' => "12",
    'typeCode' => "ENV")
);

$url = "https://api_link";//Api Link
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

But it didn't show any result and no error

Comment: The result variable is empty or what?

Comment: Result variable is empty

Comment: It may be the api, it may just be dropping the request because of bad authentication method, look at the return headers.

Comment: `'password' => "xxx,` Fix that syntax error first

Comment: What endpoint are you using? Does it go over plain HTTP or HTTPS? What headers are in `$headers`? Are you sure the API expects JSON data? Add some debugging info, like `CURLOPT_HEADER`, `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, check the return code with `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`...

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't initialize your cURL resource. Where is your `curl_init()` ?

```
$ch = curl_init();       // without this, there is no cURL to execute
```

Also fix the syntax error I mentioned in a comment above. Also check for errors

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: when I used the above code it showing "Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Comment: Then you also need to disable SSL verification option for your cURL call. You can issue another `setopt` call for that. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !function_exists('curl_version') )
    die("Curl function is disabled");
```

Check if curl_function is enabled or not

Comment: I checked with the above code curl function is enabled

Comment: is $ch = curl_init(); defined?