# Twilio exception with certificate

Tags: php, curl, twilio

I have used curl to connect with https://api.twilio.com/
Everything was working fine till 27th september, 2014 but now it is not working and giving me an exception that says: "Curl failed with error Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

I have checked for this exception and found either to upgrade the php library file for twilio or disable the certificate checking. I have tried with both the options but nothing works.

Also i have one more doubt, if the exception is related to SSL certificate then if I disable the certificate checking than it should work properly, but its not working.

Please suggest me something as soon as possible.

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok

Comment: Or considering the timing, it may be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099849/amazon-marketplacewebserviceorders-requests-suddenly-failing-php-curl-giving-ss

Comment: Rik, Were either of those helpful for your problem?