# Choosing certificate for HTTPS cURL error: 58 - unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok), madrai says:

> If you are sure about the service endpoint url, hit it through browser, save the certificate manually in "X 509 certificate with chain (PEM)" format.

How do I know which certificate to choose? In Firefox, under Tools → Options → Advanced → View Certificates → Authorities, you can't see which cert the current tab is using. You just get a huge long list from A to Z. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to view the certificate from the site's favicon (inside the upper-left red square): [image: Security Overview]
Then click More Information (lower-right), which brings you to this screen; click View Certificate (in red square again).
[image: More Information]
Select the Details tab and hit Export.
[image: Certificate]