# Run DocuSign sample PHP code?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, docusignapi

When running [this PHP code](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate) on my server with the addition of adding my info at the top and changing line 27 to:

`echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . " " . curl_error($curl);`

I get this error:

> error calling webservice, status is:0 SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok/16495053#16495053

Comment: The link provided by LugiHaue worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to set the curl handler to ignore SSL errors (assuming you are testing this on a local machine). The syntax is:

```
curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Please don't use this in production as it is not secure.

Comment: @LugiHaue's answer is correct, this answer will identify that this is indeed the problem. But should not be implemented.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Hence the reason not to implement this in production. This is the quick fix for testing locally if you don't want to download certs to a development machine. I agree that LugiHaue has the better production environment answer.