# ssl certificate in curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to find solution for my problem and I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok).
I implement it and get this error

```
cURL Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

This is what I did saving the cacert.pem, I copy and paste it to notepad and put this to my path **C:\xampp\htdocs\test**  and  when I save it, it turns to **cacert.pem.txt**. I don't know if this is the right way to do it. The post said need a PATHTO(which folder cacert.pem save, I think). I put this to php.ini

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cacert.pem.txt"
```

and this is the code of my curl.

```
function curl_generator($url,$postData = array()){

    if($url){
        $data_string = json_encode($postData);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cacert.pem.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {                
            echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);  
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way. I'm now confuse and no idea of error.

Comment: Why do you need to install an SSL certificate? CURL is capable of reading a site's installed certificate

Comment: @Machavity OP said the certificate is self-signed, so unless you somehow add a CA chain to a trusted root (even if that's your own root), the connection will fail. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: because  I can't find other way to connect. I try this curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); but no response I get

Comment: @user3818576 What do you mean by "no response"? What is the HTTP status code?

Comment: @Machavity I get this error if I used that code cURL Error: Failed connect to sample.com:443; No error

Comment: I assume it is a certificate error. so i try the code for certificate

Comment: @Mike Can't validate a self signed. But my question is why he needs to do this. You can connect to a site with SSL installed and CURL will negotiate like a browser

Comment: @Machavity  I dont have response now. I already fix the cURL Error: Failed connect to sample.com:443; No error .

Comment: @Mike saving  cacert.pem in notepad. Is it a right way to do it?

Comment: @Machavity I get an error URL Error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: g:\cacert.pem CApath: none

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? You're not providing us any context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
```

With

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: or  If you want to add certificate add in same folder root where are you running your script not in php.ini  and provide path to that certificate