# PHP crawler not working for wikipedia

Tags: php, parsing, web-crawler, wiki

Below is my php code to output the text under the id=Summary. Well this script is working fine for other webistes but not for wikipedia.I have also pasted the error I am getting below. Is wikipedia restricting the parser script? if so, is there any solution to parse and get the content from wiki?
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php


function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);


//    var_dump($doc->loadHTMLFile($url)); die;
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    if(!$result) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $doc->loadHTML($result);
    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

//Here I am dispalying the output in bold text
echo getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time', 'Summary');
?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to load http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php(49): getElementByIdAsString() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php on line 25
```

Comment: What is the CURL error you are getting?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php this function would return the errer from CURL

Comment: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS and SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)

Comment: I have tried, but didn't work..can you correct my code to functional if possible..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's looks like it's a duplicate of this: [php crawler for wiki getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213767/php-crawler-for-wiki-getting-error/36213889#36213889)

the reason is that the curl try to verify cert so just adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

remove the problem, but i sugest to use all of this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```