# php crawler for wiki getting error

Tags: php, parsing, web-crawler

In the below code I am trying to extract the content from the website using the php code, which is working fine when I use getElementByIdAsString('www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'synopsis');

But it is not working when I use the same code to extract content from wikipedia, getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time', 'Summary');

Below is my code and the exception I am getting when I use the latter one.Can someone correct my code to extract wikipedia content based on the id

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php


function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);


//    var_dump($doc->loadHTMLFile($url)); die;
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    if(!$result) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $doc->loadHTML($result);
    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

//Here I am dispalying the output in bold text
echo getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time', 'Summary');

?>
```

Exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to load http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php(40): getElementByIdAsString() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php on line 18
```

Your help would be very greatful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Update after discuss in comment:

```
<?php

function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    if(!$result) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $doc->loadHTML($result);
    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    $output = '';
    $node = $element->parentNode;

    while(true) {
        $node = $node->nextSibling;
        if(!$node) {
            break;
        }
        if($node->nodeName == 'p') {
            $output .= $node->nodeValue;
        }
        if($node->nodeName == 'h2') {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

//Here I am dispalying the output in bold text
var_dump(getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time', 'Summary'));
```

You probably could also use xPaths or just use the whole response and cut whatever you want with regex

Comment: Liszka This time it is not returning any error, but I am getting a blank page without any content..is there anyway to pull out the specific content without using id

Comment: when I run this code that gets me the "<span class="mw-headline" id="Summary">Summary</span>" so basically I think it works correct as you use your function as getElementById (so the same effect as use $("#Summary") in the chrome console. What you are trying to achive ? 

Maybe try var_dump the output except echo it ?  

var_dump(getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time', 'Summary'));

Comment: I jus wanted to extract the text under Summary tab.

Comment: Awesome dude :-) Thank you soo much :-)

Comment: no problem, my pleasure :)