# How do Integrate eWay Payment System in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card

I have followed the document site `https://eway.io/api-v3/` to integrate the Payment system into my PHP application. And I run the command `composer require eway/eway-rapid-php` from terminal in the application. After that I load `autoload.php`.

Now I want to send customer into eWay payment site for choose payment method(paypal, CC) as well as paypal/CC information. So that customer can feel that they are paying by eWay payment gateway. I have the following code into my controller method:

```
$apiKey = '5XwiMIQ3EBkSlP5XwiMIQ3EBkSlP5XwiMIQ3EBkSlP...................';
    $apiPassword = '12222......';
    $apiEndpoint = \Eway\Rapid\Client::MODE_SANDBOX; // Use \Eway\Rapid\Client::MODE_PRODUCTION when you go live

    $client = \Eway\Rapid::createClient($apiKey, $apiPassword, $apiEndpoint);

    $transaction = [
        'RedirectUrl' => 'http://www.eway.com.au',
        'CancelUrl' => "http://www.eway.com.au",
        'TransactionType' => \Eway\Rapid\Enum\TransactionType::PURCHASE,
        'Payment' => [
            'TotalAmount' => 1000,
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->createTransaction(\Eway\Rapid\Enum\ApiMethod::RESPONSIVE_SHARED, $transaction);
```

It's returning the `"Error connecting to Rapid gateway"` | error code `S9992`
Also I followed the url `https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php`.

Do I miss anything? Would you please help me out?

Comment: have you googled the error code? What did you find at https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php?  Is your api key right? Have you set up your details on the service and have you checked that you have the rights to connect?

Comment: @AndrewWelch : I googled the error but nothing found for myself. API is is right. I have set the service to get the service. How do I check the rights to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time a `S9992` connection error is due to an incorrect CA bundle, which prevents SSL verification from working correctly. There are a number of questions with solutions already on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053/628267).

You can confirm the issue by enabling logging in the eWAY PHP SDK, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/incarnate/bfddd8fc31281bacb8d4) has some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same Eway S9992 issue using XAMPP on Mac OSX. I managed to fix the issue by downloading the latest CA bundle from here:

[https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem)

Saving it to my /Applications/XAMPP/etc/ folder then editing my XAMPP/etc/php.ini file and updating the path to the openssl.cafile:

```
openssl.cafile=/Applications/XAMPP/etc/cacert.pem
```

Restarted Apache and it worked a treat!

Comment: I am using Apache instead of XAMPP. May I edit in php.ini file ?

Comment: Of course, the A in XAMPP stands for Apache, it's just one of the included applications - (Cross-Platform (X), Apache (A), MariaDB (M), PHP (P) and Perl (P)). 
Just hunt down the location of your php.ini and make the adjustment.