# PHP handshake fail TLS1.0

Tags: php, ssl, php-openssl

I try to connect via `fsockopen` to `sendm.cert.legalmail.it` on `465` port, is SMTPS service called PEC in italy.

With any version of PHP i have tried this snippet work:

```
<?php
fsockopen('tls://sendm.cert.legalmail.it', 465);
```

all it's ok with `OpenSSL 1.0.2h`, if i upgrade to `OpenSSL 1.0.2j` this snippet fail with this error:

```
    PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure in ~/Development/experimental/php-handshake/connect.php on line 3
    PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in ~/Development/experimental/php-handshake/connect.php on line 3
    PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to tls://sendm.cert.legalmail.it:465 (Unknown error) in ~/Development/experimental/php-handshake/connect.php on line 3
```

So with `OpenSSL 1.0.2j` i try to connect via command line:

```
openssl s_client -connect sendm.cert.legalmail.it:465
```

It works perfectly.

I try check SSL on the server with [testssl](https://testssl.sh/) this is the dump (stripped):

```
SSLv2               not offered (OK)
SSLv3               not offered (OK)
TLS 1               offered
TLS 1.1             not offered
TLS 1.2             not offered
Version tolerance   downgraded to TLSv1.0 (OK)
```

Only `TLS 1` is avaiable, i try to force the handshake to TLS1 with this uri: `'tlsv1.0:://sendm.cert.legalmail.it'` but the result is the same.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, tested with PHP5.6 and PHP7.1.

Where is the bug? in openssl? in PHP? in the server handshake?

*Update* if i look at chiper always with `./testssl.sh -E sendm.cert.legalmail.it:465` with `OpenSSL 1.0.2j` return:

```
x05     RC4-SHA                           RSA        RC4       128      TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                           
x04     RC4-MD5                           RSA        RC4       128      TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                           
x16     EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA              DH 1024    3DES      168      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                  
x0a     DES-CBC3-SHA                      RSA        3DES      168      TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                      
x15     EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA               DH 1024    DES       56       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                       
x09     DES-CBC-SHA                       RSA        DES       56       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                           
x14     EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA           DH(512)    DES       40,exp   TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA              
x08     EXP-DES-CBC-SHA                   RSA(512)   DES       40,exp   TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA                  
x06     EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5                   RSA(512)   RC2       40,exp   TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5                 
x03     EXP-RC4-MD5                       RSA(512)   RC4       40,exp   TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
```

With the version `OpenSSL 1.0.2h`

```
x05     RC4-SHA                           RSA        RC4       128       
x04     RC4-MD5                           RSA        RC4       128       
x16     EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA              DH 1024    3DES      168       
x0a     DES-CBC3-SHA                      RSA        3DES      168
```

And php const `OPENSSL_DEFAULT_STREAM_CIPHERS` is the same accross all versione it contains:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!RC4:!ADH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research i find why:

PHP has a `OPENSSL_DEFAULT_STREAM_CIPHERS` which contains the default query for openssl, with this command:

```
openssl ciphers -v `php -r 'echo OPENSSL_DEFAULT_STREAM_CIPHERS;'`
```

i get all ciphers PHP can handle with the current version of openssl installed.

Between `1.0.2h` and `1.0.2j` the same query return different ciphers list a drop support for these:

1. `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA`
2. `DES-CBC3-SHA`

So by default the PHP can't handle the connection correctly, but if i force the `$context` with this cipher the connection take place:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers' => 'EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA',
        ],
    ]
);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
  'tls://sendm.cert.legalmail.it:465',
  $errno,
  $errstr,
  30,
  STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
  $context
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else experiencing the same issue: it seems that Legalmail TLS server now supports TLSv1.2, so this is not a problem anymore with them.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer completely: look at answer here [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)

This is probably the cause for fsock as well as curl.
Although his question is on windows / xampp, I suppose it will help, I suppose the one who upgraded the OS did not merge the php.ini with new version(s)

Comment: but this question isn't about cert validation, it fail on handshake.