# Curl, SSL: certificate verification failed

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have problem with curl requests on El Capitan 10.11.4, PHP 7.0.12, CURL 7.50.3. When I try to make requests to https services then I see error:
**Curl failed with error #51: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)**

Do you have idea how can I fix it?

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://google.ch');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (FALSE === $content)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: You could add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); as a quickfix. A better way is described here http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: but now (with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`) I see: Curl failed with error #35: SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled

Comment: You might also need curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
There is more info about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok

Comment: Now I have:
`$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://google.ch');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);` 
and still I have the same error...

Comment: Did you try the other and better solution by exporting the certificate and set cacert.pem to curl.cainfo ? As described in both links?

Comment: I see that I can add certificate: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'path/to/cert');` but how can I generate cert file?

Comment: This file doesn't work :/ https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. I see error...

Comment: You need to grab the certificate from the url you want to use curl on. Did you do that? See my first link.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded cert file from https://pki.google.com/ and it works :) Thank you Bolli!