# Curl Error : error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

Tags: php, curl, openssl, payment-gateway

I'm working on a payment system integration for a website. For now I'm testing on a local computer with xampp. I have submitted a `.csr` file to the bank server, then they provide me the `.crt` file. I do have a `.key` file too.

When I try to submit the certificate and some value to the bank server with including certificate file path (`.crt`) and `.key` file, it throws the error:

> Curl Error : error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

My code is:

```
 $twpg_gateway_url = '<bankurl>';
    $twpg_cert_file = getcwd().'<.crtfile with path>'; 
    $twpg_key_file = getcwd().'<.keyfile with path>';
    $twpg_key_password = '';
    $curl = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
        //CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => $twpg_gateway_url . '/Exec',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/xml'),
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
    );

    if ($twpg_cert_file != '') {
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLCERT] = $twpg_cert_file;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEY] = $twpg_key_file;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD] = $twpg_key_password;
    }

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$response)
    {
        echo "Curl Error : " . curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
```

Comment: Are you adding the directory separator after the `getcwd`? file permissions? - what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @belthazorNv wasn't thankyou for addressing, i have done that now but now it throw me:
 Curl Error : error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca .... do you know what might cause this?

Comment: You need to specify a CA to use for path validation. Where are you adding the CA to root trust? Did you omit some code or are you not doing it? Also see [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6400300/608639)

Comment: Some of these options look dangerous, like [`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html). Are you sure you should be using them in an application that handles financial data? I doubt it will pass a PCI audit.

Comment: also add error checking to your setopt calls! setopt and setopt_array returns bool(false) if there was a problem setting your options, which your code completely ignores! (add a check with a runtime exception)

Comment: @jww thats what i dont understand , I'm new in this ssl thing, I don't understand what CA is, is it something i need to store in project file? or is the one that is downloaded from CURL website?

Comment: I'm getting the same error using the same method for a p12 file, and searches I do for the error just drop me into StackOverflow. It's like dead ends unless I become an expert at OpenSSL, PHP cURL, and PKCS#12.