# Imagick stopped working in xampp

Tags: php, openssl, imagick, php-openssl

Installed Imagick in Xampp using [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows) link. It was working properly but stopped working all of sudden.

Only thing I did in between, tried to configure gmail stmp setting in zend 3. Though I am not sure but it stopped working after that.

This is the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Imagick::__construct(): SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php:55
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php(55):
>   Imagick->__construct('https://storage...') #1 {main} Next
>   ImagickException: Failed to read the file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php:55 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php(55):
>   Imagick->__construct('https://storage...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php on line 55

[image: line of having error]

**Edit 1**

Followed [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) link and changed

curl.cainfo ="C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem"

openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem"

this is the error I am getting now

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file in C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php:55 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php(55): Imagick->__construct('https://storage...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\restau\restau\public\image.php on line 55
```

Below is the code in which image is not getting loaded, this was working properly until few days ago.

```
<img src="/image.php?filename=https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxx/uploads_56ea606ea4685.jpg&amp;width=380&amp;height=255" alt="">
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That does not look like a problem of Imagick, but of OpenSSL. Obviously, you are trying to connect to a URL with a non-verifable certificate. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok

Comment: thanks for replying. I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you try this using `file_get_contents`? Also, I don't think the Google servers use CACert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed this problem.

I replaced this part of code

```
if(filter_var($imagePath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $imagick = new Imagick($imagePath);
} else {
    $imagick = new Imagick(getcwd().$imagePath);
}
```

with this

```
if(filter_var($imagePath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  $tempFile = 'temp/file-'.uniqid().'.jpg';
  copy($imagePath, $tempFile);
  $imagick = new Imagick(getcwd().'/'.$tempFile);
  unlink(getcwd().'/'.$tempFile);
} else {
  $imagick = new Imagick(getcwd().$imagePath);
}
```